# show certain products in a category on home page in magento 2

Tags: product-view, cms-pages

I added a widget on a homepage and selected a categories from a drop down to include some items from a category (73)- I have 5 items to show up. I am not sure why but it only displays the 5 oldest products from that categories, anyways I can pick certain items to display or even show the newer items? 
I tried to shows only certain SKU. by selecting SKU instead of Category from drop down, it works with one SKU but when I do multiple SKUs the widget doesnt work. is there something I am missing?

Thanks
Roger

Comment: What do you choose in the conditions of widget options?

Comment: I tried entering the sku number in condition - like i said works fine with one sku, when selecting multiple skus it does not work. regarding the category selection i just select the category in condition, again it only shows older items